# Explicit probability distribution for a Gaussian family of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_{ij}$ are random variables on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},p)$, for each $i,j = 1,...,n$. Let me call $X = (X_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{N}$ the associated random vector, which has $N^{2}$ entries. Suppose these random variables $X_{ij}$ are i.i.d and $\mathcal{N}(0,\frac{1}{N})$. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{N^{2}}\to \mathbb{R}$. I want to compute an expression for the expectation $\mathbb{E}[f\circ X]$. According to my calculations, this should be:
$$\mathbb{E}[f\circ X] = \bigg{(}\frac{N}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\bigg{)}^{N}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{N^{2}}}f(x)e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i,j=1}^{N}N^{2}x_{ij}^{2}}dx$$
with the abbreviation $x = (x_{ij})$. I am not entirely sure of this formula, because I am unsure if I am using the correct product measure. Is my formula correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density for each $X_{ij}$ is
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi/N}} e^{-x_{ij}^2/(2/N)} dx_{ij}
\end{equation}
(Note here that the variance $\sigma^2$ is $1/N$, not the standard deviation).

Since the $X_{ij}$ are i.i.d., the expression for $\mathbb{E}[f \circ X]$ would be
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[ f \circ X] = \left ( \frac{N}{2\pi} \right)^{N^2/2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{N^2}} f(x) \,\exp \left( - {\frac{N}{2} \sum_{i,j = 1}^N x_{ij}^2} \right) \,dx.
\end{equation}